# binary vs continuous and binary vs nominal

Tags: r, data-visualization, python, binary-data, continuous-data

I am playing with a data set and want to show the correlation between one variable (binary (delayed)) against rest of the variables (departure time, destination and the date) but I do not have any idea of the plot I could use

Which plot  could I use to  show the correlation between my binary variable, the rest of the variables? Here is a sample of the data

[image]

Comment: Hi, please provide sample data if you can, even just a 'head(data)' so we can understand how the data is constructed.

Comment: A sample of the data set has been provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how the data exactly fits to the variables mentioned in a question, but I understand what you are trying to say.

What you could try is a bar chart (showing an average value for this variable for example), but instead of showing just one bar for each variable you could provide two, showing the average value for this variable for instances of each value in your binary variable. I would advise to colour-code them to make it more easy for people to compare.

This approach could of course be extended into other visualization techniques which allow for analysis of more complex patterns in your dataset like boxplots etc.

Hope this helps!